# Bellman Ford's algorithm with negative cycles

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, cycle, bellman-ford

So if I'm trying to find the shortest path using Bellman Ford's algorithm using this method to test if there is a path:

```
public boolean hasPath(int v){
    return distTo[v] < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

If I have a negative cycle then what happens to this algorithm? Does it still return true because I know that Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work with negative cycles but what about Ford's?

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking the absolute then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but the value may or may not be the shortest path. The real shortest path may be actually negative infinity, because if the negative circle reaches the destination node, there will be always a shorter path than the current shortest path.

This is actually how you use Bellman-Ford to detect negative circles. If after |V| loops, the (|V|+1)th still updates some shortest path, there is a negative circle in the graph.